# Why the AJAX don't work here?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, pdo

i'm trying to learn to use AJAX, so i search a tut about make a crappy login system with ajax and start to learn, the thing is i do some little modifications to it, (PDO instead my_sql for example) and is not working, seeing that tut over and over again doesn't seems to show why there is not working.

**What happend than doesn't work?**

Well, it moves me from the index.php page to the admin.php page instantly, it musn't be that way, if i'm correct, it must bring the data back to the index.php right?

it works if the AJAX doesn't exist, instead of bring the data from admin.php, it makes me move to that page, like if it was pure PHP and none AJAX involved in the script.

The PHP is not calling the AJAX, it just use header(location

Thats the problem.

Here is the code of all files:

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_POST){
include("3325d7a55a4550ee85156f5f9a6762bede9d3021.php");
 $nombre = $_POST['login'];
 $pw = $_POST['pwd'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tuser WHERE USER = :USER");
    $rslt = $stmt->execute(array(':USER' => $nombre));
    $stmt->bindParam(':USER', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $usuario = $stmt->fetch();  


    if ($usuario) {
        $_SESSION['usuario_logeado'] = $usuario;
        header('Location: admin.php');
    } else {
        $error = 'Usuario y/o password incorrecto.';
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();


                $.post('ajax.php', $(this).serialize(), function(resp) {
                    if(!resp.error) {
                        var html= '<h3>Hola, ' + resp.['NOMBR1'] + ' ' + resp.['NOMBR3'] + '!</h3>' + '<p>' + 
                        '<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>' +
                        '</p>';

                    $('.sidebar').html(html);
                    } else {
                        var error = '<p class="error">' + 'Usuario y/o password incorrecto.' + '</p>';

                        $('#login-form .error').remove();

                        $('.actions').before(error);
                    };
                }, 'json');
            });
        });
    </script>       
</head>
<body>
<h5>INDEX!!!</h5>
<center>
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['usuario_logeado'])): ?>
<form id="login-form" action="" method="post" class="form-stacked">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login">
    <input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
<?php if(isset($error)): ?>
    <p> 
        <?php echo $error ?>
    </p>
<?php endif;?>  
    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="btn">
</form>
<?php else :?>
    <h3>Hola, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario_logeado']['NOMBR1'] .' '. $_SESSION['usuario_logeado']['NOMBR3'] ?></h3>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php endif;?>
<br />
<br />
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<br />
<br />
<div class="actions"></div>
<br />
<br />
<a href="admin.php">Admin</a>
<br />
<br />
<div id="RBUG"> Si tienes cualquier duda, problema tecnico o quieres dar una sugerencia usa el 
<a href=RBuGFm.php>Reporte de Bugs</a> </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!$_SESSION['usuario_logeado']){
    header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporis</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>      
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h4>TROLOLOLOLO!</h4>

<h3>Hola, <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario_logeado']['NOMBR1'] .' '. $_SESSION['usuario_logeado']['NOMBR3'] ?></h3>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>

<div id="RBUG"> Si tienes cualquier duda, problema tecnico o quieres dar una sugerencia usa el 
<a href=RBuGFm.php>Reporte de Bugs</a> </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include("3325d7a55a4550ee85156f5f9a6762bede9d3021.php");
 $nombre = $_POST['login'];
 $pw = $_POST['pwd'];

    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tuser WHERE USER = :USER");
    $rslt = $stmt->execute(array(':USER' => $nombre));
    $stmt->bindParam(':USER', $nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $usuario = $stmt->fetch();  


if ($usuario) {
    $_SESSION['usuario_logeado'] = $usuario;
    echo json_encode($usuario);
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}

?>
```

3325d7a55a4550ee85156f5f9a6762bede9d3021.php (conection.php)

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pss = "password";
$db = "somedb_name";

$authz = "authc";

// Los comandos auxiliares estan comentados para que no funcionen a menos que sean necesarios

// var_dump($_POST);

try{
    $con = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db,$user,$pss);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // echo "Success ";

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage;
}
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

I don't know what can be the problem and i'm running out of ideas, so i'm trusting in your eyes and experience to solve my problem and learn how to do this stuff correctly..

Any comment, suggestion, question improvement or question about it for clarification, please feel free to say it, and i try to edit the post with the answer as soon as i can.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to pick a title that somewhat reflects your problem. What you wrote is meaningless

Comment: Are there any errors thrown in console? Side note `<center>` tag is deprecated

Comment: " it moves me from the index.php page to the admin.php page instantly". You mean, when you load the index.php the first time ?

Comment: @Brewal it means the AJAX is not working, instead of bring the data from admin.php, it makes me move to that page, like if it was pure PHP and none AJAX involved. Thanks for make it notice, i clarify the "Whats wrong" part

Comment: @charletfl 1) Modified, 2) Nope, none, 3) Note Taken, any alternative to it?
Thanks!